# Catalytic hydrogenation of polycyclic hydrocarbons

Tags: organic-chemistry

Recently I came across a question-[image]

The compound on the left undergoes catalytic hydrogenation to yield A(not B, according to the answer). My knowledge is limited to the stereospecificity of catalytic hydrogenation, and I don't know if it's regioselective as well or not. Why do we get A as a product and not B? There are 3 moles of hydrogen provided, so how to decide which 3 multiple bonds would be reduced in such a situation? Can someone provide me with a detailed answer?

Comment: Consider the ring strain in the [4] rings. The bonds are much less stable and more reactive

Comment: The anti-aromatic rings are much more unstable than the aromatic ones. So, the 3 moles of hydrogen gas will prefer to reduce those sites which ultimately lead to the remobal of the AA rings